# ASP.NET Display simple data from XML using ASPX

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

Good Afternoon,

I have a page (category-list.apsx) that uses the Repeater Control method to display the xml details on the page. I used the example shown here:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

This works fine but I also need the page to display the title of the category and the company name. These will be shown at different places on the page.

How can this be done?

The XML would be called categories.xml and would be set up like:

```
<PageDetails>
        <CategoryName>Example A</CategoryName>
        <CompanyName>Company A</CompanyName>
</PageDetails>
```

For single pieces of data, would it use a asp label instead? Like

```
<asp:Label name="CategoryName" Text="Category Name" runat="server"/>
```

Or am I way off?

Thank you for your Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You canno't use directly your asp:label instead, because < or & are not accepted,

But you can use `CDATA` section if you want inject

```
"<![CDATA[" "]]>"
```

Comment: Is this a good way of pulling a single piece of information from a XML sheet?

Comment: yes i added in the past on my proper project, you can ask on stackoverflow